# Test is not showing passing when using should

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

i am first time testing i write a test case

```
var should = require("should")
describe('Array', function(){
  describe('#indexOf()', function(){
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present',function(){
      [1,2,3].indexOf(5).should.equal(-1);
      [1,2,3].indexOf(0).should.equal(-1);
    })
  })
})
```

its giving me 0 passing

```
 0 passing (1ms)
```

but why it should show 1 passing

Answer (score 5):

By default, if no parameters provided, mocha is looking in ./test directory.

If you saved the test above somewhere else (may be in current directory), you shall provide the path to this file as a parameter to mocha.

Assuming that test is saved in a file **test.js**, you shall execute it as following:

```
% mocha test.js
  ․
  1 passing (5ms)
```

Comment: Hey Andrei, even when I am specifying the correct path for test file, its giving me the same error.
Can you help me out in recognising what's the problem then?

Comment: @PrernaJain it is odd, I also tried to run this test and got 1 passing. Perhaps, you can share your folder structure or you can try in a fresh new folder. Don't forget to install `mocha` and `should` packages.

Answer (score 2):

For those wondering, just make sure to also have an `it(...)` section in your test. Mocha needs this to recognize that there is something here needing to be tested.